# Get post id shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I'm new at this.

I need a shortcode that returns the post id of the post in which the shortcode is inserted.

If someone could provide that it would open the doors of understanding for me :)

Much appreciated!

Comment: Look at the left side of my answer, there is a "right" sign. Please click on that. @James

Comment: I assume that is the check mark :) consider it clicked and thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place the below code to your themes `functions.php` or inside your plugin and the `[return_post_id]` shortcode will print the post ID.

```
add_shortcode( 'return_post_id', 'the_dramatist_return_post_id' );

function the_dramatist_return_post_id() {
    return get_the_ID();
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: For the official webpage for this function, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

Comment: Or `add_shortcode( 'return_post_id', 'get_the_ID' );`

Answer (score 0):

Shortcode: Embeddable Post Excerpts

After installing the shortcode (follow steps 1 + 2 below) you can execute it anywhere WordPress accepts shortcodes. To connect to a post, you simply need to enter the post ID you wish to display:

https://marketersdelight.net/snippets/embeddable-excerpts/

Comment: Link is ok, but you should also provide some code in case that someday the link will stop working and your answer becomes useless.